# unable to set the image view to be circle

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uikit

i need to make the profile photo image circle (similar to whats app)
The cell i use is UITableViewCellStyleDefault

here's my code:

```
    User *user = [DBHelper fetchUserWithUserID:userID];
    cell.imageView.image = [Helper imageWithBlob:user.profile.thumbnailPhotoBlob defaultImageFile:FILE_DEFAULT_PHOTO];
    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.frame.size.height /2;
    cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

But the result image view is still a square

EDIT: The image view's frame is {0, 0, 0, 0}, but it did show the image.

EDIT 2:

I tried the answer but the image is not circle. Here's what i did:

```
float height = [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[Helper circlizeImageView:cell.imageView cellHeihgt:height];


+ (void)circlizeImageView:(UIImageView *)imageView cellHeihgt:(float)cellHeight {
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cellHeight, cellHeight);
    [Helper circlizeView:imageView];
}
+ (void)circlizeView:(UIView *)view {
    view.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.size.height / 2;
    view.clipsToBounds = YES;
    view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I imported the entire <QuartzCore/QuartsCore.h>.

Comment: i tried QuartzCore/CoreAnimation.h not working either

Comment: Did you try to add the image view as a subView in your cell contentView?

Comment: no, but the default cell comes with the image view already

Comment: Ok because it supposed to work as is but try to add new imageView rather than use cell's imageView, just give it a try, .

Comment: yes it's working. but I want to use cell's image view to adjust the offset of label and cell separator line

Comment: is your code in `- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`  or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is all fine.

The only problem is with this line:

```
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.frame.size.height/2;
//CGRect rectTest = cell.imageView.frame;
//returns a rect of (0,0,0,0) & hence the cornerRadius being set is 0.
```

Try:

```
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10; //or some fixed value
```

---

In retrospect, what you're trying to do will not get you to make the `imageView` circular because the default `imageView` is rectangular (the height is always more than the width) and so... setting a corner radius that is half of the height/width will not work.

It'll be better if you use a custom `UITableViewCell` and add a square framed `imageView`.

ANyways... Since the default `imageView` touches the top of the default `UITableViewCell` and ends at the bottom, you can get the height of the `imageView` by using the height of the row (in case you have dynamically sized cells)

So, something as simple as this:

```
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.frame.size.height/2;
```

But none of this looks good since the `imageView` is rectangularish and cells being of dynamic height will make it look like a poor design (the fixed radius looks best imho)

Comment: ic, i just pass in the heightForRow as the radius since the imageView's frame is set only after you assign the image

Comment: @OMGPOP : the `imageView`'s frame seems to be set much after an image is assigned. So... even the `heightForRow` won't work in every case. Infact, the point is that you can't ensure every cell's `imageview` to be circular because you can't access the `imageView`'s frame. You'd be better off with a **custom** `UITableViewCell`. However... if you knew for certain that your images would always be, say, 30px by 30px, you can set cornerRadius to 15 and leave it be.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

1- Add the `imageView` as a `subView` to you cell.

2- Override `layoutSubviews` in a custom cell:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,40,40);
}
```

Comment: Yes, try to pass the size to the cell, cell.imageSize = mySize; //imageSize is a property in your cell class, and set the imageView frame according to this size.

Comment: i don't have a cell class. I register the reuse identifier in code and use system cell directly.

Comment: Ok then subclass your cell and but the above `layoutSubviews` in .m, any way i recommend to add the imageView as a subView, it is better practice.